# Why does CGridView fail to filter if we use `$criteria->condition` and/or `$criteria->params`?

Tags: yii

I have the following:

```
public function search() {
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('entity_id',$this->entity_id);
        $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
        (etc...)

        if (Yii::app()->user->role == SiteUser::ROLE_AUTHOR) {
            $userId = Yii::app()->user->getId();
            $entity = Entity::model()->find("user_id = $userId");

            $criteria->condition = 'entity_id=:entity_id';
            $criteria->params = array(':entity_id'=>$entity->id);
        }

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
```

When I apply this:

```
if (Yii::app()->user->role == SiteUser::ROLE_AUTHOR) {
 $userId = Yii::app()->user->getId();
 $entity = Entity::model()->find("user_id = $userId");

 $criteria->condition = 'entity_id=:entity_id';
 $criteria->params = array(':entity_id'=>$entity->id);
}
```

the user can only see on CGridView **is own** records. Nice.
But, for some reason, the **filter doesn't work**.

If I comment those lines:

```
 $criteria->condition = 'entity_id=:entity_id';
 $criteria->params = array(':entity_id'=>$entity->id);
```

The filter works. But, obviously, the user will see ALL users records.

Update:
If instead of using *condition* and *params* properties I use `compare()` method, like this:

```
$criteria->compare('entity_id',$entity->id);
```

It works.

**Why does it work with compare, and NOT with condition and params?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use this

```
if (Yii::app()->user->role == SiteUser::ROLE_AUTHOR) {
            $userId = Yii::app()->user->getId();
            $entity = Entity::model()->find("user_id = $userId");

            $criteria->condition = 'entity_id=:entity_id';
            $criteria->params = array(':entity_id'=>$entity->id);
        }
```

what happens is the condition property is reset (due to the fresh assignment), the compare function you have used earlier appends the comparison to the the condition see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#compare-detail for information on how this works, therfore when you do a fresh assignment it clears all the existing conditions.

Therefore Either you can use a new criteria object like below

```
if (Yii::app()->user->role == SiteUser::ROLE_AUTHOR) {
                $userId = Yii::app()->user->getId();
                $entity = Entity::model()->find("user_id = $userId");

                $criteria2= new CDbCriteria();
                $criteria2->condition = 'entity_id=:entity_id';
                $criteria2->params = array(':entity_id'=>$entity->id);
                $criteria->mergeWith($criteria2);
            }
```

or you can move the logic for `SiteUser::ROLE_AUTHOR` before the compare statements